# Combine lots of CSV files in CentOS?

Tags: linux, csv

I have a CentOS machine and I want to combine .csv data.

I have thousands of small documents all with the same column information.

How would I go about combining all of them into files of up to 20Mb in size?

For example 1.csv would combine the first few files and once the 20Mb limit is reached the data will continue to go into 2.csv and so on.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Check this out ! http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80611/merging-multiple-csv-files-without-merging-the-header

Comment: You should probably use a language like `python` to acheive what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If they don't have headers, something as simple as;

```
$ cat *.csv > combined.csv
```

would work (we run in the directory containing the files (assuming you want them in the order returned by `ls *.csv`)).

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive what you want with simple tail command :

```
tail -q -n+2 *.csv
```

You only need to add the proper header column afterward.

Comment: Could you give me the full command? Plus how would you add the 20 mb file size limit?

Comment: I guess the 20mb limit will take a brand new Question

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look at the `join` utility: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/join-invocation.html#join-invocation